# Active Directory / Powershell - How to identify if a server, in a federated cluster, is down

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, directoryservices

This question is in the context of a service that is running on a DC server (or is accessing the DC remotely) such that the service can access Active Directory, but the service has no awareness of the Active Directory servers, how many servers there should be, what the server addresses are, etc...

Furthermore, the service must be written under the assumption that the Active Directory setup could involve a group of Federated servers.

So to illustrate the problem by way of an example -

Say I'm trying to run a very simple AD query, via Powershell v2 (or you could use Directory Services), to get all of the ADUsers:

$users = Get-ADUser

Now let's assume that the example company, Contoso, has an AD server in New York (for their NY office), and one in Seattle (for their Seattle office). Also, the service will be pointing to the DC which will be the server in the NY data center.

So for the purposes of simplicity, let's just say that $users returns two user objects with display-name attributes of:

Dan Jump
Jim Wilson

Now let's assume that the Seattle server is down so I run the query again and just get:

Dan Jump

From what I understand - AD will not return an error indicating that the Seattle server is down..it will just return the users it can find..

I know it's possible to detect deleted objects so, if I saved a list of all the users, I could potentially verify that the user was deleted...but that's a bit of overhead especially if I'm interested in more than just a list of users

So is there a way to detect one or more AD servers, in a Federated cluster, are down before I even run my query?

Comment: 1. A 'federated cluster' of 'AD servers' - could you clarify?  AD comes in domains and forests.  You can have trusts between domains and between forests but usually the word 'federation' is applied to SAML or WS-Federation scenarios.  2. Apps don't have to be configured to know DC names because of the DC Locator mechanism.  3. Active Directory uses multimaster replication which gives loose consistency with convergence meaning all users within a domain should eventually be on every DC.  Given all of this, your question doesn't make much sense to me.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: I was speaking to a WS-Federation scenario, but this was just to illustrate one possible scenario. The program that would be running this query is a service that would run on an Active Directory Domain Controller such that the service is completely ignorant of the trusts between domains and forests. The service is using Directory Services to obtain all of the user and group information for as far as it has permission to see across all forests and domains. It can be assumed that the service has access to what it needs, to begin with,but I'm not clear how to identify when something goes missing

Comment: ...some of the AD versions may be older, but the example I am attempting to illustrate is supposedly an actual example. While I'm sure you have primarily valid points, I was informed that I will have several scenarios where I can't rely on replication (based on historical experience) and will have to face the fact that some data may live on certain servers that may be inaccessible at times. If that doesn't make sense then I'll just have to go back to the person who told me that would be the case...

Comment: ...but those are the cards I have been dealt and I don't have any control over the Exchange setup for the servers I will be working with. I have not done much work with Exchange before so please forgive me if my explanation is frustrating. I'm just trying to make sense of this, but can't seem to find the right search terms... or maybe I'm just chasing ghosts :/ Please let me know if you think I am indeed chasing ghosts :)

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying - I don't come here as often as before because IMO some of the moderation is over-zealous and it's spoilt the atmosphere of the place.  Anyway, first-off WS-Federation has got nothing to do with the problem you're trying to solve, so you can shelve anything they've told you about that.  The service can be ignorant of the domain topology but once you have access to a DC the info you need can be obtained via a query.  And, if they can't rely on replication, AD is broken.

Comment: Are your queries involving LDAP referrals?  If not, it shouldn't matter that a DC is down, if replication is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809.aspx), before you make use of any of the following.  S.DS and S.DS.AD abstract a lot of what happens but there's a lot of useful information in there and it might help you to clarify your requirements.

I'm not aware that there's a function to return DCs that are down but the [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwzcae1f.aspx) namespace contains classes you need to determine domain topology.  For example, the [Forest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.aspx) class will return a collection of [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.aspx) objects (and [Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectorysite.aspx)s and many other useful properties).  [Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.aspx) will give you access to a collection of [DomainController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincontroller.aspx) objects( as well as the [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.children.aspx) and Parent domains and many other props and methods).

You could iterate over the domains to get all DCs and then iterate over the DCs and try a ping although this may not work in a well-secured and segmented network.  You might consider trying to connect to each DC using S.DS.DirectoryEntry as that should work, from a DC, in any scenario.  Of course, if your network guys have been overzealous with their locking-down, even that might not work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the wonderful people of [www.serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)

I do not see how this is programmer specific? It sounds like network troubleshooting? Anyways...

IMO, it depends where your federation servers are located. Are they in the cloud? Are they virtual? If so, it's easy to detect when they go down, through simple API calls to your server platform.

Or you could try to implement a server ping mechanism, like the example on this website [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/let-powershell-do-an-inventory-of-your-servers/):

```
$servers = Get-Content 'servers.txt'
ForEach-Object ($server in $servers) {
   # Ping the machine to see if it's on the network
   $results = Get-WMIObject -query "select StatusCode from
Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"
   $responds = $false  
   ForEach-Object ($result in $results) {
      # If the machine responds break out of the result loop and indicate success
      if ($result.statuscode -eq 0) {
         $responds = $true
         break
      }
   }
         If ($responds) {
      # Gather info from the server because it responds
      Write-Output "$server responds"
   } else {
      # Let the user know we couldn't connect to the server
      Write-Output "$server does not respond"
   }
}
```

** This assumes your servers are "pingable".

You could probably also make use of **AD-GetComputer cmdlet** found on MS Technet [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx)

> The Get-ADComputer cmdlet gets a computer or performs a search to retrieve multiple computers.
>
> The Identity parameter specifies the Active Directory computer to
>   retrieve. You can identify a computer by its distinguished name (DN),
>   GUID, security identifier (SID) or Security Accounts Manager (SAM)
>   account name. You can also set the parameter to a computer object
>   variable, such as $ or pass a computer object
>   through the pipeline to the Identity parameter.
>
> To search for and retrieve more than one computer, use the Filter or
>   LDAPFilter parameters. The Filter parameter uses the PowerShell
>   Expression Language to write query strings for Active Directory.
>   PowerShell Expression Language syntax provides rich type conversion
>   support for value types received by the Filter parameter. For more
>   information about the Filter parameter syntax, see
>   about_ActiveDirectory_Filter. If you have existing LDAP query strings,
>   you can use the LDAPFilter parameter.
>
> This cmdlet retrieves a default set of computer object properties. To
>   retrieve additional properties use the Properties parameter. For more
>   information about the how to determine the properties for computer
>   objects, see the Properties parameter description.

Comment: this does not answer the question: "the service has no awareness of the Active Directory servers, how many servers there should be, what the server addresses are, etc..."

Comment: How can you run AD queries if you dont even know you have AD servers? This question will never have an answer because its too vague and open ended.

Comment: Well that's with the caveat that "This question is in the context of a service that is running on a DC server (or is accessing the DC remotely)" ... so if you run a powershell query like "Get-ADUser" it's going to get all of the users including users that exist on other servers within that federated group of servers